# binomial approximation problem

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

consider the probability that more than 38 out of 142 DVDs will work correctly.

Assume the probability that a given DVD will work correctly is 46%.

specify  whether the normal curve can be used as an approximation to the binomial probability by verifying the necessary conditions.

Ans : Yes / No

I think  we use here n=38 and p =0.46
and n*p and n*(1-p) both are > 5 , so its  normal approximation to binomial ? Is it correct or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$n = 142$, $p = 0.46$, $np = 65.32$, $n(1-p) = 76.68$. We need to compute,

$$1-\sum_{i=0}^{38}\binom{n}{i}p^i(1-p)^{n-i}$$

which can be approximated using $\Phi(38; \mu, \sigma^2)$ where $\mu = np, \sigma^2 = np(1-p)$.

**Edit**: As mentioned in the comments by Michael Hardy, the continuity correction of $0.5$ can greatly improve the approximation. So, a better approximation would be

$$1-\Phi(38.5;\mu,\sigma^2)$$

To better understand how this approximation works please check Example $3.3.2$ of Statistical Inference Second Edition by George Casella and Roger L. Berger.

Comment: but probability is given for DVD work correctly, so n will be 38 ? Or we use total n DVDs?

Comment: n*p is 142*0.46 , or 38*0.46?

Comment: To clarify this doubt, I suggest you to write the expression of probability that exactly $5$ DVDs out of $142$ DVDs work correctly where the probability that a randomly chosen DVD works correctly is $p = 0.46$. Write that expression in comment.

Comment: x =5 , n = 142 ,  p =0.46 , so n*p = 0.46*142 ?

Comment: thanks. now clearly understand

Comment: $-1$ because you didn't do a continuity correction. $\qquad$

Comment: Note that $>38$ is the same as $\ge 39,$ so you do a continuity correction using $3.85.$ You get $$ 1-\Phi\left( \frac{38.5 - np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}} \right). $$

Comment: That's right. That $0.5$ correction does make the approximation better. I did remember it but probably got lazy in mentioning it in the post. Thanks for pointing it out. Edited the answer.